# How to access https 443 port in kubernetes in windows using kind and docker

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, kind

`kubectl port-forward service/nginx 8080:443`

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 443
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 443
Handling connection for 8080
E0314 16:38:47.834517   25527 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 8080 -> 443: error forwarding port 443 to pod bb5e0e3b270881ce659aa820d29dd47170e229abb90fb128e255467a8dba606a, uid : failed to execute portforward in network namespace "/var/run/netns/cni-5ef7f945-3c15-25c0-8540-39513d9d3285": failed to connect to localhost:443 inside namespace "bb5e0e3b270881ce659aa820d29dd47170e229abb90fb128e255467a8dba606a", IPv4: dial tcp4 **127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused IPv6 dial tcp6 [::1]:443: connect: connection refused
E0314 16:38:47.834846   25527 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod**
```

`the same working with port 80`

Answer (score 1):

The command used is as follows:

```
kubectl port-forward pod/<pod-name> <local-port>:<exposed-port>
```

where **local-port** is the port from which the container will be accessed from the browser while the **exposed-port** is the port on which the container listens to which is defined with the **EXPOSE** command  in the Dockerfile.

The error **failed to connect to localhost:443** resembles that there is no process listening on **port 443**. The dockerfile used to create the nginx image exposes port 80 and nginx is configured to listen on **port 80** by **default**.

In order to establish a connection using port 443,please change the ngnix config file to listen on port 443 instead of port 80. Also, please update the docker image with the corresponding changes.

As you have not shared the nginx configuration file, the default **nginx.conf** file will be as follows:

```
server { 
    listen  ${PORT}; 
    server_name localhost;
 
    location / { 
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html; 
        index index.html index.htm; 
    } 


    include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf; 
}
```

Please update the **{PORT}** to **443** in the above template and in DockerFile please add the below line:

```
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

For more details please look into the below documentations:

[Link_1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) [Link_2](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/kubectl-port-forward/)

Comment: I'm using docker desktop+ WSL2, so where I need to modify this nginx file I found in below locations ```:~$ locate nginx.conf
/usr/local/kong/nginx.conf
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf.default```

Comment: @newbie Please update the default nginx configuration /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf.default

Comment: yeah also i installed certificate then it's worked